# Setting custom request headers in the app directory of Next.js doesn't seem to work

Tags: next.js

Here is my middleware.ts file. I can confirm that it gets hit and does all the things it's supposed to:

```js
// packages/webapp/middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  const authorizationHeader = requestHeaders.get('authorization')
  const bearerToken = authorizationHeader?.split(' ')[1]
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(bearerToken!)

  if (typeof decodedToken !== 'object' || decodedToken === null) {
    return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed' }),
      { status: 401, headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }
    )
  }

  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })

  response.headers.set('x-user-id', decodedToken.user_id)

  return response
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: '/api/:path*',
}
```

In my API, I have:

```js
// src/app/(authenticated)/conversations/api/route.ts
import { Conversation } from "common/types/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


export async function GET(request: Request) {
  console.log('headers', request.headers)
  console.log('userId', request.headers.get('x-user-id'))
  const conversations = ...
  return NextResponse.json({ data: conversations })
}
```

But I don't have `x-user-id` set. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Next.js 13 with the App Router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the header before creating the response is working for me. Like below:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  const authorizationHeader = requestHeaders.get("authorization");
  const bearerToken = authorizationHeader?.split(" ")[1];
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(bearerToken!);
  
  if (typeof decodedToken !== "object" || decodedToken === null) {
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Authentication failed" }), {
      status: 401,
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    });
  }

  requestHeaders.set("x-user-id", decodedToken.user_id); // 

  // 
  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you're here, and need to set/modify headers in the app directory:

```
 return NextResponse.json('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `token=${token.value}` },
  })
```

[source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#cookies)